# Does ElasticSearch store a duplicate copy of each record?

Tags: elasticsearch, storage

I started looking into ElasticSearch, and most examples of creating and reading involve POSTing data to the ElasticSearch server and then doing a GET to retrieve them.

Is this data that is POSTed stored separately by the ElasticSearch server? **So, if I want to use ElasticSearch with MongoDB, does the raw data, not including the search indices, get stored twice (once copy for MongoDB and one for ElasticSearch)?**

In conjunction with an answer to this question, a description or a link to a description of how ElasticSearch and the primary data store interact would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ElasticSearch can only search within its own data store, so a separate copy will be there.

You can use the mongodb connector to keep the data in elastic in sync with the mongo database: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector

Comment: At first I thought that might be a hindrance to using ElasticSearch, but I guess having a backup copy of your data is a good thing. :)

Comment: That's one way of seeing it :-). I wouldn't count it as a backup though - it's not always easy to read the data back into the original db and its good to always regard your elastic db as disposable (especially initially you will probably drop it a lot and repopulate because of index type mismatches)